# Копирование значения атрибута только в соседний тег

Tags: jquery

Друзья, есть такая разметка. Как скопировать значение из value в соседний span?
Такой код подставляет значение из первого input во все span с классом value. Нужно копировать значение только в соседний span.

```
<ul class="list">
    <li class="item">
        <span class="text">lorem</span>
        <input class="input" type="text" value="1000"> - 
        <span class="value"></span>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
        <span class="text">lorem</span>
        <input class="input" type="text" value="3000"> - 
        <span class="value"></span>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
        <span class="text">lorem</span>
        <input class="input" type="text" value="5000"> - 
        <span class="value"></span>
    </li>
</ul>

<script>
  $(".item").find(".input").siblings(".value").text($(".input").val());
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(".item .input").each(function() {
  $(this).siblings(".value").text($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
  <li class="item">
    <span class="text">lorem</span>
    <input class="input" type="text" value="1000"> -
    <span class="value"></span>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <span class="text">lorem</span>
    <input class="input" type="text" value="3000"> -
    <span class="value"></span>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <span class="text">lorem</span>
    <input class="input" type="text" value="5000"> -
    <span class="value"></span>
  </li>
</ul>
```